# How to solve this issue : On play Store Should not use keywords that indicate store performance or ranking

Tags: android

Your app may not be promoted on Google Play because your short description does not meet the following guidelines:
Should not use keywords that indicate store performance or ranking

Answer (score 0):

Change your "short description".